# conda: "specifications were found to be in conflict"; package install fails

Tags: installation, package, anaconda, conda

I was using conda to install a package called stomel (conda install stomel). I did add the correct channel to .condarc.

The error showed that The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

- stomel

I know this kind of error would be normal when using conda to install package. But should there be two or more packages that are in conflict? Besides, I never install stomel before.

I would really appreciate any answers. Thank you in advance. Attached are the error message.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0v7R.png)

Comment: This means that `stomel` conflicts with one of the other packages in your environment. Try `conda install stomel --alt-hint`

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this gives me exactly the same error message. All I need to find is which one is in conflict with the stomel package.

Comment: @darthbith: `conda install ---alt-hint` option doesn't exist in 4.4.x and seems to have been undocumented.

Comment: @smci Yes, apparently it was removed here: https://github.com/conda/conda/commit/3a76ba8a4be6c44356983c1a83bf51fd454ddd92  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

This problem is fixed. Here is the link.
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3324
Instead of finding out what is in conflict with stomel, I can build a new python environment.